# Is there a way I can use this Javascript / jQuery function multiple times on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.clicktoshow').each(function(i){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $('.showclick').eq(i).show();
                $('.clicktoshow').eq(i).hide();
            });
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
<style>
.clicktoshow{
cursor: pointer;
}
.showclick{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

I want to use the above code to hide and show 4 different section (each with 2 subsections but the two will show on a single click of the corresponding list item) on the same page, here is what I have written:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.clicktoshowsatin').each(function(i){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $('.showclicksatin').eq(i).show();
                    $('.clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb, .clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb').eq(i).hide();
                    $('.clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb, .clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb').hide();
                }); 
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.clicktoshowsilk').each(function(i){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $('.showclicksilk').eq(i).show();
                    $('.clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb, .clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb').eq(i).hide();
                    $('.clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb, .clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb').hide();
                }); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.clicktoshowcrepe').each(function(i){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $('.showclickcrepe').eq(i).show();
                    $('.clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb, clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb, clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb').eq(i).hide();
                    $('.clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb, clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb, clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb').hide();
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, here is the link to the website I am trying to implement this: http://justadire.com/

Comment: I recommend using a class that's common to all of the elements, in order to better observe [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles. It might help to include your HTML and build a [demonstration of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This was the initial thing, but, i need one button to show just one of the and hide the rest, another button to show another one and hide the rest, please, you can check the website here: http://justadire.com and see the first section after the hero section (The one with the select category section, with BROCADE, SATIN, SILK, CREPE), you can try to click on SATIN to see what I am talking about. Thanks for your contribution. :)

Answer (score -2):

You could write

```
<script>
    function addHandler(material) {
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.clicktoshow' + material).each(function(i){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $('.showclick' + material).eq(i).show();
                    $('.clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb, clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb, clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb').eq(i).hide();
                    $('.clicktoshowcrepemain, .clicktoshowcrepemainb, clicktoshowsilkmain, .clicktoshowsilkmainb, clicktoshowsatinmain, .clicktoshowsatinmainb').hide();
                });
            });
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        addHandler('silk');
        addHandler('satin');
        addHandler('crepe');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Somehow, this did not work, the (material), how am I suppose to add it, I am working on Elementor, WordPress. What I could do is to use div classes and IDs (I think). I am not a JavaScript expert :(

Thanks for your help though, looking forward to further solutions, please. thanks again.